# How can I tell whether a .PFX file requires a password

Tags: .net, x509certificate2

In .NET, I'm loading a certificate from a .PFX file using the following:

```
var signingCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxFileName);
```

If the .PFX file requires a password, it throws a `CryptographicException`. How can I tell that the file requires a password (so that I can prompt for one)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always test for that exception.  =)

```
try
{
    //some stuff
}
catch (CryptographicException ex)
{
    //Now you Know!
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //and knowing is half the battle
}
```

Comment: Nope. That only tells me that there was a `CryptographicException`. I'd then have to check that the text matched.

Comment: Checking the text of an exception is not usually a good idea. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you suggesting that when opening the file without a password, there is potential for throwing a CryptographicException that is *not* due to the need for a password?

Comment: Yes. For example: what if the needed cipher suite has been disabled by group policy?

Comment: Sorry - this is the only way I can see to do it **within this class**.  I looked for some stuff outside of that scope but it's scarce as well (as I'm sure you know).